# Genie Segfaults on easy typecast

Tags: segmentation-fault, vala, genie

I have Valac 0.30 installed.  Running the following code,

```
[indent=4]
init
    str : string
    str = "Hello World";
    data : array of uint8
    data = (array of uint8) str;
    print "%i\n", data.length;
```

I get a segfault.  GDB tells me this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:36
36  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

I've seen some other people with this problem, but none of them got solutions which have worked for me.

Comment: The important part of what GDB tells you is the line about the segmentation fault. Then it tells you the function where it happened, including file-name and line-number. The problem here is that the crash happened in a library function, and you don't have the source to the standard library installed. That's not an error you should worry about, instead you need to look at the function call stack (using the `bt` command) to find out where in *your* code the crash happened. It also helps if you could look at the generated C code as that's where you will be pointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the compiler to hard cast a `string` into an `array of uint8`, however those types are not assignment compatible.

Under the hood the simplified generated C code (which you can get with `valac -C`) looks like this:

```c
#include <glib.h>

int main (void) {
        gchar* str = g_strdup ("Hello World");
        // Ouch: A negative number is used as length for g_memdup
        // This will produce a segfault, because the parameter is unsigned and will overflow to a very big number.
        // The string is only 11 bytes long however
        guint8* data = g_memdup (str, -1 * sizeof(guint8));
        int data_length1 = -1;
        g_print ("%i\n\n", data_length1);
        g_free (data);
        g_free (str);
        return 0;
}
```

The [`string` data type](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/string) has two properties that are meant for what you are trying to do (Vala syntax):

```cs
public int length { get; }
public uint8[] data { get; }
```

So you could write your code like this:

```py
[indent=4]
init
    str: string = "Hello World";
    print "%i\n", str.length;
```

Or like this:

```py
[indent=4]
init
    str: string = "Hello World";
    data: array of uint8 = str.data;
    print "%i\n", data.length;
```

For completeness here is the `gdb` backtrace:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/src/genie/Test
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_avx_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S:245
245             vmovdqu -0x80(%rsi,%rdx), %xmm5
(gdb) bt
#0  __memcpy_avx_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S:245
#1  0x00007ffff78b66c6 in memcpy (__len=4294967295, __src=0x60cdd0, __dest=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/bits/string3.h:53
#2  g_memdup (mem=0x60cdd0, byte_size=4294967295) at /usr/src/debug/dev-libs/glib-2.46.2-r2/glib-2.46.2/glib/gstrfuncs.c:392
#3  0x00000000004007d6 in _vala_array_dup1 (self=0x60cdd0 "Hello World", length=-1) at /home/user/src/genie/Test.gs:6
#4  0x000000000040085e in _vala_main (args=0x7fffffffdf78, args_length1=1) at /home/user/src/genie/Test.gs:6
#5  0x00000000004008f5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf78) at /home/user/src/genie/Test.gs:2
```

So `g_memdup` is trying to copy 4294967295 bytes from an 11 byte string here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Explains everything.  I found the code snippet above in a library I've been trying to use.  Been such a headache.  Thanks again.